# Dropdown menu does not stay selected via php after refreshing the page

Tags: php, html

The following script would let the user to chose between on and off. The problem is that the selected value does not stay selected after refreshing the page. Any idea how to fix this?

```
<form action="Conf.php" name="Calculation" method="post">      
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) 
        {
            $Wave = $_POST['WaveHMap'];
        }
    ?>

    <?php 
        $attr = 'selected="selected"'; 
    ?>

    Wave Height Maps: &nbsp;
    <select selected="selected" name="WaveHMap" VALUE="<?PHP print $Wave ; ?>">
        <?php $attr= 'selected="selected"'; ?>
        <option VALUE="On"<?php echo  $Wave == 'On' ? $attr : '';  ?>>On</option>
        <option VALUE="Off"<?php echo  $Wave== 'Off' ? $attr : ''; ?>>off</option> 
    </select>
    <Input Type="Submit" Name="Submit1" Value="Save Parameters">
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you setting $Wave?  Also, `'selected="selected"'` doesn't make sense on a `select` element, only on an `option` element.

Comment: So should I change the code to this? <option selected="selected" VALUE="On"  <?php echo    $WaveHeightMaps == 'On' ? $attr : ''; ?>>On</option>
      <option selected="selected" VALUE="Off"  <?php echo  $WaveHeightMaps== 'Off' ? $attr : '';?>>off</option>

Comment: I have already did but now I see the second selection after refreshing the window.

Comment: I meant you can change the `<select selected="selected"`.  Post the line of cod ewhere $Wave is set so it will help me to see if there is anything wrong there.

Comment: Try making VALUE all lowercase in the HTML.  I don't think this should make a difference but it's worth trying.

Comment: Also, try removing selected and VALUe attributes from this line: `<select selected="selected" name="WaveHMap" VALUE="<?PHP print $Wave ; ?>">`

Comment: I have tried it. No luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select  name="WaveHMap" >
        <option VALUE="On" <?php echo $Wave == 'On' ? 'selected' : '';  ?>>On</option>
        <option VALUE="Off" <?php echo $Wave== 'Off' ? 'selected': ''; ?>>off</option> 
    </select>
```